# pyrogram: Client produce KeyError while starting the bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

When I am starting my telegram bot by Pyrogram using the latest version `v2.0.103`

```py
app = Client("BillyKaiChengBot",api_id="apiid",api_hash=os.environ['API'],bot_token=os.environ['TOKEN'])
    
with app: #error produces here
    loginapp = app.send_message(channel_id, "login")

#my own code
#.
#.
#.
app.run()
```

This code can run smoothly until recently, it produces this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    with app:
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 280, in __enter__
    return self.start()
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 58, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 40, in connect
    await self.load_session()
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 584, in load_session
    await Auth(
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 254, in create
    raise e
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 89, in create
    res_pq = await self.invoke(raw.functions.ReqPqMulti(nonce=nonce))
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 67, in invoke
    return self.unpack(response)
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/auth.py", line 60, in unpack
    return TLObject.read(b)
  File "/home/runner/billy-telegram/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/raw/core/tl_object.py", line 33, in read
    return cast(TLObject, objects[int.from_bytes(b.read(4), "little")]).read(b, *args)
KeyError: 0
```

I tried to reinstall the module but it not works.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see `KeyError` in that error report...

Comment: sorry I didnt copy the error code completely. You can see my edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [owner response](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/1249#issuecomment-1501055946) in GitHub, the main reason of this issue is caused by server or network issue, not from the code or module itself.

> The issue is related to empty responses received from the server and is not reproducible consistently. It's very likely just a momentary server or network issue

Answer (score 0):

You are combining 2 ways of calling `app.run()`.

---

You should use it like so, where you pass a function to `run`:

```
app = Client("my_account")

async def main():
    async with app:
        print(await app.get_me())


app.run(main())
```

OR, if you don't want a `main()`, you can also do:

```py
app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
async def echo(client, message):
    await message.reply(message.text)


app.run()  # Automatically start() and idle()
```

Note that in the second example, there is no `with app`, that's were your error is coming from. Pick one of those.

---

Both snippets are part of [pyrogram's examples](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/).